# Get rid of tracking email being sent when we don't offer tracking as a option

Tags: email

When our customers get sent a confirmation email it states a "we will send an email with a link to track your order". We do not offer this and would like to remove this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of Magento you are using but if you're using Magento1 you should go to  **System > Transactionnal Emails** and create a new template.

You'll then have the option to load the "new order" email template and modify it the way you want to.